# Which would have the greatest processor cost?

Tags: java, serial-port, execution-time

I have a class, as such:

```
 private class verifierListener implements SerialPortEventListener {

    String outBuffer;
    char charBuffer;

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if (event.isRXCHAR()) {//If data is available
            timeOut = 1000;
            lastReadTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (event.getEventValue() > 0) {//Check bytes count in the input buffer

                try {
                     byte[] buffer = verifierPort.readBytes(event.getEventValue());
                     //INSERT CODE HERE
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

With two possible methods of implementation(in the `INSERT CODE HERE` area)

Case A:

```
                        outBuffer = new String(buffer);


                        bfrFile.print(outBuffer);
                        sysOutWriter.append(outBuffer);
```

Case B:

```
                            for(byte bt : buffer) {
                                charBuffer = (char) bt;
                                bfrFile.print(charBuffer);
                                sysOutWriter.append(charBuffer);
                            }
```

Both compile and run, and do what they are supposed to do.  But I'm trying to make this code perform as seamlessly as possible, so I don't possibly risk a loss of transmitted data on a lower end PC.

I'm assuming that case A will have more overhead due to the String initialization, but I wanted to make certain before I remove it.

Can y'all tell which one would be cleaner, and/or how to determine the processing cost for each?

Comment: You can easily determine this yourself.  Build stand-alone test cases with each method, executed each in a loop enough times to get the total run time something over 60 seconds.  Then use the other method and see which runs faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be loosing any data, even on a lower-end PC.  That's because there are (several) buffers in between your code and the actual data that's coming over the serial port(operating system buffers, Java buffers, etc..).  Speed-wise, unless you're running this code a lot(as in, several thousand times per second) you shouldn't notice a difference.

Assuming this is a standard serial connection, and you were running at 115200 bits per second, that means that you're getting at most 14,400 characters per second.  Even if you were to read those one character at a time, you shouldn't see a big speed hit.

Answer (score 1):

if your using windows ctrl-alt-delete and view the thread when its running and see the memory that it uses. As far as your code goes, may I suggest you use a StringBuilder instead of String. I'm not sure if there really is a difference in overhead, but from a good code / programming perspective it should be A.